Selenium Firefox event page load complete
I want to make a code run when page is COMPLETE.
if like a address do action if not do another action
Like this:
If (url==1) {}else{}

I want run that when page refresh or navigate repeatedly.
Like we completed in web browser in C#.

you should probably add more details here.... Selenium already waits for standard page loads.  It will not wait for JS triggered updates.  WebDriverWaits are designed to deal with JS updates.

Selenium already waits for standard page loads!!?
This is exactly my question
How do I do this?

you don't need to do anything.  If a page is loaded after a selenium driver method it will automatically wait for the page to load.  (after a .get(), click(), etc...)  It may not wait for refresh, back or forward, though.  If a standard page load does not happen, though you need a webdriverwait.  JS populating DOM.   It should be noted that some sites will "lazy load" content via JS after a standard page load happens.
